# PHP foreach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops, foreach

How can i make a loop like this one in Javascript?

```
foreach ($viewData['cure'] as $cure)
```

In this loop I would like to print the result in JS

```
$("#new").append('<label for="nice_text">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" VALUE="<?php echo (string)$cure["id_type"] ?>"/>');
```

Comment: What's wrong with a normal `for` loop?

Comment: Try jQuery's `.each()` function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 4):

You can simply combine both like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php foreach ($viewData['cure'] as $cure): ?>
$("#new").append('<label for="nice_text<?php echo $cure["id"] ?>">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text<?php echo $cure["id"] ?>"/>" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" value="<?php echo (string)$cure["id_type"] ?>"/>');
<?php endforeach; ?>
</script>
```

Just make sure your Ids are unique (I added `$cure["id"]` as an example), you might also wanna change the `name="cureIdtype"`, depending on what you want to do with the input afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Was googling this for myself to see if there was something more elegant than what I have below and didn't see my solution mentioned.

PHP

```
foreach ( $viewData['cure'] as $cure ) {
    ?>
    // your code from above
    $("#new").append('<label for="nice_text">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $cure["id_type"]; ?>"/>');
    <?php
}
```

Javascript

```
var cures = <?php echo json_encode( $viewData['cure'] ); ?>;
for ( var key in cures ) {
    var cure = cures[key];
    // your code from above modified to use the Javascript variable created
    $("#new").append('<label for="nice_text">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" value="'+cure["id_type"]+'"/>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is one of the way you can write or use forEach in Javascript.

```js
const arr = ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'];
arr.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Also you can refer [this link](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-difference-between-foreach-and-for-in-992db038e4c2) which helps you to understand difference between for and forEach in javascript.

```js
const arr = ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'];
for (let i in arr) {  
  console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have `foreach` like PHP, you need to use a regular `for` loop.

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (var index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    console.log(a[index]);
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)

Comment: As @silentw, stated, there is a .forEach method that can be used to iterate through an array. 

Reference:  
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP and echo the content to the browser, it would look like this:

```
foreach ($viewData['cure'] as $cure) {
    echo '$("#new").append("<label for=\'nice_text\'>ID Type</label><input type=\'text\' id=\'nice_text\' name=\'cureIdtype\' class=\'input-text\' VALUE=\'' . (string)$cure['id_type'] . '\'/>")';
}
```

If you have a JavaScript array and want to handle this there, it would look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewData['cure'].length; ++i) {
    $("#new").append('<label for="nice_text">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" VALUE="' + viewData['cure'][i]['id_type'] + '"/>")';
}
```

These examples are untested, and littered with a variety of single/double quotes and escapes, so I could have made some typos in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
a.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I don't understand what is the problem with your code...

```
<script>
var array = [];
<? foreach ($viewData['cure'] as $cure) {?>
    array.push(<? echo $cure?>);
<? }?>
array.forEach(function(value){
    $("#new").append('<label for="nice_text">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" VALUE="'+value+'"/>')
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript Array forEach() Method

### Description:

Javascript array **forEach()** method calls a function for each element in the array.

### Syntax:

`array.forEach(callback[, thisObject]);`

Here is the detail of parameters:

- **callback :** Function to test each element of the array.
- **thisObject :** Object to use as this when executing callback.

### Return Value:

Returns created array.

### Compatibility:

This method is a JavaScript extension to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it may not be present in other implementations of the standard. To make it work you need to add following code at the top of your script:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

### Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Array forEach Method</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}

function printBr(element, index, array) {
  document.write("<br />[" + index + "] is " + element ); 
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].forEach(printBr);
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will produce following result:

```
[0] is 12
[1] is 5
[2] is 8
[3] is 130
[4] is 44
```

To understand it in better way you can [Try it yourself](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_112).

<kbd>[SOURCE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_foreach.htm)</kbd>